# Alternative to Remmina

Tags: rdp

I often have to do some work from home, so I connect via VPN and RPD to my Workplace!

Unfortunately with Remmina I can´t get AltGr-Shortcuts working, it doesn´t show TextCursor in Editors and the Performance is also not very well which is really annoying when you have to work a few hours with it!

So does anyone know a better RDP-Client for Linux it doesn´t have to be OpenSource or Free, I'm willing to pay for a good RPD-Client!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try freeRDP (http://www.freerdp.com/) which is wrapped by Remmina and provides all the actual functionality. I got the same problem as you. And got my problem solved in freeRDP. It's very easy to use: `xfreerdp -d [domain] -u [user name] -p [password] -f [ip]`, while `-f` means full screen.

Comment: Remmina 1.1.2 was released 2 months ago, doesn't look dead to me :)

Comment: @Joril, removed the misleading sentence. :)

Answer (score 7):

- [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/)  - terminal app.

or

- [krdc](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/krdc/) - part of KDE

[image]

Comment: rdesktop was used by remmina till v0.8 now it uses freeRDP which supports much more than rdesktop but still in the current-Version it´s not what I´m looking for...switching to KDE is also not an Option for me but if found this iTap http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp which works very well and the price of $20 is affordable, anyway I will accept your answer ;)

Comment: krdc works really well for me, thus far.

Answer (score 1):

2Xclient is a very nice and stable application 
[2xclient]

http://www.2x.com/rdp-client/windows-linux-mac/

Comment: Looks like 2X client can't do RPD, using the Linux client on Ubuntu 14.04 amd64.